# Top aligning of text of unordered list

Tags: html, css

Following is my code in which i am using inline styling for aliging the text to top with the corresponding image but the inline css not working kindly let me know how can i modify the following code , so the text will be aligned to top with the corresponding image.

```
<ul style="font-size:17px;vertical-align:top; margin-top:0;">
<li style="list-style-image: url(images/check.png);">Text is not aligning to topText is not aligning to topText is not aligning to topText is not aligning to topText is not aligning to topText is not aligning to top</li>
<li style="list-style-image: url(images/check.png);">Text is not aligning to topText is not aligning to topText is not aligning to topText is not aligning to topText is not aligning to topText is not aligning to topText is not aligning to topText is not aligning to top</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Could you include the image for your list item?

Comment: @MikeB use this url http://img253.imageshack.us/img253/149/02yespw9.gif FOR IMAGE, and use width of div 100px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not your code.

You can even remove some of the unnecessary markup.

Your image that is causing the headache.  It needs adjusted in order for your bullets to line up with the text.

*I did some more tinkering, it is the images size.  The image height is taller than the row you need to scale it down*

Also you have to be careful with `verticle-align` it doesn't always work the way you expect. [Reference](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)

Comment: The `linked fiddle` link is broken. Can you restore it, please?

Comment: @Barnee Sorry I looked around and am not able to find the fiddle I referenced. I took out the reference, but in relation to the question being asked it was an issue with the image size.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to create media blocks, one of the most common components of the web. Nicole Sullivan, one of the most famous names in CSS, has a great post talking about the nature of media blocks and giving an excellent standard implementation.

http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/

I highly recommend either using her implementation or reading hers to learn how it's done.

Comment: Well I already did that what's being told over there but i thought i should do it with `ordered list`, so isn't it possible to make text align to top?

Comment: Just put the media block inside the list item. That's one of the strengths of the media block pattern: it can be dropped in to whatever context is needed. THAT SAID: yes, it is absolutely possible to make the text align to the top with regular list items. It looks like MikeB has shown how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

set position for your background img as left center